# OpenGL black screen

Tags: java, opengl

Hi there im trying to create an OOA OpenGL project, i have two classes Mainproject and ground(mind ground isnt a ground but a line circle) i cant call it onto the main project for some reason, all i get is a black screen

**MainProject class**

```
 package cg;
 import cg.ground;
 import java.awt.Frame;
 import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

 import javax.media.opengl.GL;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;


 import com.sun.opengl.util.Animator;


 public class MainProject implements GLEventListener {

     private ground g = new ground();


             public MainProject(ground ground)
             {
                 this.g = ground;
             }


    @Override
      public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
         GL gl = drawable.getGL();

         // Clear the drawing area
         gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

         g.display(drawable);

         // Flush all drawing operations to the graphics card
     }

    @Override
    public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable arg0, boolean arg1, boolean arg2) {


    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

         GL gl = drawable.getGL();

         // Enable VSync
         gl.setSwapInterval(1);

         // Setup the drawing area and shading mode
         gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
         gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH); // try setting this to GL_FLAT and see what happens.
     }



    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame frame = new Frame("Simple JOGL Application");
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();
 //                canvas.addGLEventListener(new MainProject());
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        final Animator animator = new Animator(canvas);

        //add an anonymous WindowListener for the AWT Frame to stop the animator
         frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

             @Override
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                 // Run this on another thread than the AWT event queue to
                 // make sure the call to Animator.stop() completes before
                 // exiting
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {

                     public void run() {
                         animator.stop();
                         System.exit(0);
                     }
                 }).start();
             }
         });

         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         animator.start();

     }

 }
```

**Ground**

```
 package cg;

 import java.awt.Frame;
 import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
 import javax.media.opengl.GL;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;


 public class ground implements GLEventListener{


     public static void main(String[] args) {
     }

     public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

     }
     @Override
      public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
         GL gl = drawable.getGL();

         // Clear the drawing area
         gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

         gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);    // Set the current drawing color to red

          gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_STRIP);
          for (int deg = 0; deg <= 360; deg++) {
              double rad = Math.toRadians(deg);
              double x = 0.95*Math.cos(rad);
              double y = 0.95*Math.sin(rad);
              gl.glVertex2d(x, y);
          }
          gl.glEnd();


         // Flush all drawing operations to the graphics card
         gl.glFlush();
     }

     public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

     }

     public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable, boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged) {

     }

 }
```

Comment: You should avoid deprecated OpenGL. Take one of [these samples](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle) get first it running, and then start building your circle from there. What you are missing probably is some view matrix

Comment: Is the display method called? Looks as you haven't registered the event handler (line is commented out). And why do you have two main methods?

Comment: @elect you're great for making that github repo. Fighting the good fight against legacy GL and all that stuff.

Comment: Oh @WearyWanderer, you can't image how glad I am reading that, seriously :) it's the first time someone tell me that :). I hope you will be happy to know that I am on my way for [apitest](https://github.com/elect86/glTest) too :p

Comment: @elect do you have a sample that has object orientation in it? id love to see it

Comment: What do you mean? Model, view and projection matrix? Which OpenGL are you on?

Comment: I just want to draw a 2D shape on OpenGL in Netbeans using an object orientation design.

Comment: Then take the sample I gave you and draw in image space by using an orthographic projection matrix with (0, width, 0, height) where those are the dimension of your window. Start by yourself, I can assist you on your way, open an issue on the repo if you need help

Comment: @elect Awesome, love it!